# How can I update data in mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my `animals` table in the mySQL database:

```
| id | animal | name | number |
|----|--------|------|--------| 
| 2  |  cat   | john |  6345  |  
| 2  | mouse  | fred |  7463  |
| 3  | monkey | noah |  2342  |
```

I insert data from a text file, which looks like this (for example):

```
animal=dog
name=alan
animal=frog
name=sam
animal=bird
name=mike
```

This is my code:

```
$id = 1
$sql = "INSERT INTO animals (animal,name,id) values(?,?,?)";
foreach($list as $row) {
$q->execute(array($row['animal'], $row['name'], $id));
}
```

After the insert my `animals` table looks like this:

```
| id | animal | name | number |
|----|--------|------|--------|
| 1  |  dog   | alan |        |
| 1  |  frog  | sam  |        |
| 1  |  bird  | mike |        | 
| 2  |  cat   | john |  6345  |  
| 2  | mouse  | fred |  7463  |
| 3  | monkey | noah |  2342  |
```

Later I have another text file which looks like this:

```
number=1425
number=9824
number=9932
```

The numbers are in exactly the same order like the data from the first text file. So what I want to do is just add the numbers, so that my table would look like this:

```
| id | animal | name | number |
|----|--------|------|--------|
| 1  |  dog   | alan |  1425  |
| 1  |  frog  | sam  |  9824  |
| 1  |  bird  | mike |  9932  | 
| 2  |  cat   | john |  6345  |  
| 2  | mouse  | fred |  7463  |
| 3  | monkey | noah |  2342  |
```

But I do not know how to do this in one statement. I hope you can help. Thank you very much!

Comment: you can use update statement..

Comment: What is going on with the `id` in these records?

Comment: Use the MySQL `UPDATE` statement.
Now logically, you can't. The second text file does not have any reference to which number goes to which row.

Comment: @raveenanigam: Yes, I know the UPDATE statement, which looks like this `$sql = "UPDATE animals SET number='1425' WHERE id=1";` But how does the database know that `1425` needs to be at position `dog` and `9824` at position `frog` and so on..

Comment: @beerwin: The second text file will have the reference that all the content has the `id=1` and the content has the same order like the in the first text file

Comment: More importantly to be able to use your database in a manner in which databases were designed to be used... your `id` field should almost **never have duplicates**. I say "almost" because there are very rare instances where it is not necessary. Duplicate values in the `id` field defeats the main purpose of an `id` field. The `id` field should be auto incremented for every row. It makes things like what you're wanting to now so much easier.

Comment: @Jarla I would rather not rely on the order of the data in the table (very recent and unpleasant personal experience). The order of the data is not deterministic in the database unless you specify it in an order column and sort with that. You might end up having the numbers added to the wrong rows in this setup.

Comment: Ok, yes, I was afraid, there is no way to achieve it in this way. I will try another solution! But thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are wanting to update the "numbers" in your SQL table?

If so, you will need some sort of identifier to identify the rows which should be affected. So, if you want to set number=235443534 where the animal is equal to "Dog" then you will need to put that identifier in your text file. You may wanted to make the file colon seperated (;)?

Once you have got an identifer, you will need to read the file and loop through it.

```
<?php
$fileName = "FileNameHere.txt";
$fileToOpen = fopen($fileName,"r") or die("Error opening file :'(");
$readFile = fread($fileToOpen,filesize($fileName));

foreach($readFile as $fileLine){
 $item = split(";",$fileLine); //this will return an array {dog,34423}
 $sql = "UPDATE `animals' SET number='".$item[1]."' WHERE animal='".$item[0]."'";
 //Run your SQL and any cool code here...
}

fclose($fileToOpen);
?>
```

For more about SQL update and working with files have a look at W3Schools tutorials. They're really good! :D

Comment: Hello thank you, this looks very good. But isn't there a way like for example tell the database: start from the first entry with id=1 and go down and update the rest of the data?

Comment: You can do it the way you have said. Just instead of referencing the animal in the text file, reference the ID instead. However, upon closer inspection, you have IDs with the same value. Which could cause a problem. Ensure that you have a unique identifier for the update

Comment: I will think about it and test it. Thank you very much for your help!